# Why is function(global, factory) used in so many JS libraries?

Tags: javascript

In so many JavaScript libraries, I see `global, factory` as parameters of functions.
Eg:

**jQuery**:

```
( function( global, factory ) {

    "use strict";

    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
//...
```

**Vue.js**:

```
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
  (global = global || self, global.Vue = factory());
}(this, function () { 'use strict';

  /*  */

// ...
```

There probably are much more examples...

My question is: Why is the `global` and `factory` used as parameters so often and what are they?

Comment: Those specific names are probably the output of some module bundler, but look up “JavaScript UMD” for a good starting point.

Comment: It's the [UMD pattern](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) header

Comment: You have some missing code to fully explain jQuery but you can clearly see that `factory` is `function () { 'use strict'; /* */ ...`

Comment: @slebetman I'm afraid I don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: You can see in your own code example, `global` is `this`  and `factory` is `function () {...`. The code declares a function, for our purposes let's give it a name `foo` - `function foo (global, factory) {...}`. Then it calls it `foo(this, function () { 'use strict' ...`. But it does so without giving it a name like we did so it looks like this: `(function (global, factory) {...}( this, function () {'use strict'; ...})`. It is basically an IIFE

Comment: @slebetman if the function is declared without a name how does it get called? will the function get called immediately when we import the script?

Comment: ah nvm, it is immediately called, the term is IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), sorry this is first time I hear it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As mentioned by several people in the comments, **the real answer is that this is the structure of UMD modules.**

I'm writing this as an answer primarily because it's hard to illustrate this in comments. But you can clearly see what the code is doing in your Vue.js example:

```
    ┌──────────────────┐       ┌──────────────────┐
    │                  ▼       ▼                  │
    │    (function (global, factory) {            │
    │                                             │
    │                                             │
    │        /* deleted for clarity */            │
    │                 ┌───────────────────────────┘
    │                 │
    │    }(this, function () { 'use strict';
    │       │
    └───────┘
             /* */

         })
```

So basically it is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). You can rewrite this construct more clearly if you give the anonymous functions names:

```
// rename function () { 'use strict' ...
function Vue () { 'use strict';
    /* */
}

// rename function (global, factory) ...
function UMD (global, factory) {
    /* deleted for clarity */ 
}

UMD(this, Vue);
```

So `global` is basically `this` which when referenced from outside of any function points to the global object (`window` in browsers and not named in node.js) and `factory` is a function that creates the Vue.js object (or jQuery in the case of jQuery). Basically `factory` is the implementation of the library.

This structure is written in such a way as not to create any unnecessary variables or functions in the global scope and thus avoid polluting the global scope and avoid variable/function name clashes with other libraries.

As for why it assigns `this` to `global`? That's because `window` is (was?) a completely unprotected variable in global scope (that's why node.js does not give it a name) and any 3rd party code can overwrite it with a different thing or modify it. If you want the original global object of the browser while using unknown 3rd party code you need to use this `this` trick.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation, can you explain more of your last paragraph? How come you can still get the original global obj with the `this` trick, if `window` is already polluted then `this` will also be polluted right? and shouldn't the renamed code become `UMD(window, Vue);` instead if we want to pass in the `window`?

Comment: @Zennichimaro Not quite. The global object is an internal C++ construct. In environments like Rhino and Nodejs the global object has no name. In Browsers the `window` variable is a pointer to the global object. Now, browsers could have just made it a regular pointer thus modifying `window` would modify the global object but it looks like `window` just inherits from the global object. If you replace `window.getElementById()` for example the `this` trick will get the original `getElementById()` function because `getElementById()` is actually a global function, not just a property of `window`

Comment: @Zennichimaro Basically, there is a scope mechanism that C++ implements internally as objects and the global scope is the C++ global object. Javascript exposes all members of the global scope (and thus object) to the `window` variable (which itself belongs to global scope). It looks like `window` is not used by C++ internally to represent global scope.

Answer (score 4):

i created tiny lib for better understand by slebetman  answare

```
   (function (global, factory) {            
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    global.tinylib= factory();         

    } (this,function() {

// your code shoud place here
    }))
```

eg: this is simple i created library

```
(function (global, factory) {            
typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = 
factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    global.tinylib = factory();         

    } (this,function() {
 -----------------------------------------mylibrary code start------------------    
 var tinylib= (function(el) {
 var obj={}
 var myelement=el

 obj.setColor=(color)=>{
 myelement.style.color=color;
  }
    return obj;
 -----------------------------------------mylibrary code end------------------    

  })
 return tinylib;
    }))
```

Usage of created Library

```
import {tinylib} from 'tinylib'
```

initialize:

```
var lib=tinylib(document.getElementById('color')) //now we use lib variable whenever we want to invoke example showen below
```

usage:

```
lib.setColor('red')
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I thought that it may be worth mentioning that `esbuild` is adding support soon for the 'global' and 'factory' ('umd') syntax.

https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/507

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32720294)