# How to make npm package that uses three.js with no dependece?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, three.js

The problem is this: I want to make a npm package that creates procedural objects for threejs. But I don't know how to link three.js in my code.
I tried to stablish a dependece and using something like

```
const THREE = require('three');

Function Example(){
return new THREE.TextureLoader()load('./textures/texture.png');
}

module.exports.Example = Example;
```

This works nice with other constructors, like scenes, and vectors, however for `TextureLoader()` it generates an error of an undefined document (because there is not document defined for this THREE). I suspect that this is not the architecture that I should use.
I saw in some libraries they *load* THREE with a function like:

```
var _loader;
myLib.install = function (libs) {
        THREE = libs.THREE;
        _loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    };
```

So in this case there is not actual dependency on three.js, calling installation function is necessary thou; therefore `require()` function is not needed anymore. I would like to understand how to implement this in my code.
Thanks beforehand for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

I found the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751410/12002015) to another question. Just changing `el` for `THREE` and using this variable to store Three.js library.
In this way I was able to generate npm package that does not installs Three.js as a dependency as I wanted.

My code can be seen [here](https://github.com/SEscobedo/artastra/blob/master/artastra.js).