# javascript - importing from file that have a few function(global, factory)

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, umd

I have a legacy code that uses `function(global, factory)` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365052/why-is-functionglobal-factory-used-in-so-many-js-libraries):

```
// legacy.js
(function (global, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        console.log('my amd One');
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        console.log('my cjs One');
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        console.log('my esm One');
        global.One = factory();
    }
})(this, function () {
    console.log('hello One');

    function One(options) {
        console.log("function One", options);
        var self = this;
        self.connect = (url) => {
            console.log('One.connect: ' + url)
        }
    }

    One.prototype.myone = function (roomId, token) {
        console.log('myone: ' + roomId + ', ' + token);
     }

    return One;
});

(function (global, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        console.log('my amd Two');
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        console.log('my cjs Two');
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        console.log('my esm Two');
        global.Two = factory();
    }
})(this, function () {
    console.log('hello Two');

    function Two(options) {
        console.log("function Two", options);
        var self = this;
        self.connect = (url) => {
            console.log('Two.connect: ' + url)
        }
    }

    Two.prototype.mytwo = function (roomId, token) { 
        console.log('mytwo: ' + roomId + ', ' + token);
    };

    return Two;
});

(function (global, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        console.log('my amd Three');
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        console.log('my cjs Three');
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        console.log('my esm Three');
        global.Three = factory();
    }
})(this, function () {
    console.log('hello Three');

    function Three(options) {
        console.log("function Three", options);
        var self = this;
        self.connect = (url) => {
            console.log('Three.connect: ' + url)
        }
    }

    Three.prototype.mythree = function (roomId, token) { 
        console.log('mythree: ' + roomId + ', ' + token);
    };

    return Three;
});
```

I have setup `webpack` with `babel` so that I can `import` all `One`, `Two`, `Three` and hopefully use it from ES6 code, however it seems like I can only use `Three` which is defined last..

I'm importing and using it like this in my es6.js

```
// es6.js
import One from './legacy'
// const legacy = require('./legacy')

// console.log(legacy)
// console.log(legacy.One)
console.log(One) // prints out Three

function initTest() {

  const one = new One('hw');
  console.log('one: ', one); // prints out an instance of Three
  // one.myone('room1', 'token1'); // this will crash, myone is undefined but idk why??
  one.mythree('room1', 'token1'); // works
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  initTest();
})
```

Anybody knows what I should do to access `One` and `Two` properly?
I've tried using named `import {One, Two, Three}` or `const legacy = require('./legacy');` to no avail..

Answer (score 1):

The module is, frankly, broken.

If you load it as a CommonJS module (which you are), then each of the IIFEs will call a line that looks like this:

> ```
> module.exports = factory();
> ```

So the first IIFE assigns `One` as the thing that is exported. Then the second IIFE **overwrites** it with `Two` and the third with `Three`.

Those IIFEs are **not designed to be in the same file**.

Move them into separate files.

Comment: Thanks it works! For my simplified `One`, `Two` and `Three`, but in the real `legacy.js` the `Three` actually refers to `Two` and `One`, do you know how I can include the new `legacy-2.js` into the now `legacy-3.js`